# Find the average of an unknown number of inputs

Tags: c, average

I need to write a C program that calculates the average, using a function, of grades entered by the user. The number of grades entered is unknown so I have to use a sentinel value -1.

This is my code and it compiles fine, however it doesn't tell me the average and the for loop doesn't call the function four times. What am I missing?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 float calculateAverage (int sumofGrades, int numberofGrades);

 int main(void) {

 int i;
 int sumofGrades = 0;
 int numberofGrades = 0;
 int grade = 0;
 float average;

 for (i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {

    calculateAverage(sumofGrades, numberofGrades);

 }
 return 0;
 }

float calculateAverage (int sumofGrades, int numberofGrades) {

float average;
int grade;

printf("Enter grades and -1 to stop: ");
scanf("%d", &grade);
while (grade <= 100 && grade != -1) {
    numberofGrades++;
    sumofGrades += grade;
    average = sumofGrades / numberofGrades;

}
printf("The average is %.2f", average);

return average;

}
```

#### Update

Thanks for the help! But I can't get it right yet. For the assignment I need the program to ask me 4 times to input the unknown number of grades and each time the average is calculated.

Also, why doesn't it stop and gives me the average once I type -1?

```
#include <stdio.h>

float calculateAverage(int sumofGrades, int numberofGrades);

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int sumofGrades = 0;
    int numberofGrades = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
        calculateAverage(sumofGrades, numberofGrades);
    }
    return 0;
}

float calculateAverage (int sumofGrades, int numberofGrades) {

    float average;
    int grade = 0;

    while (grade != -1 && grade >= 0 && grade <= 100) {
        printf("Enter grades and type -1 to stop: ");
        scanf("%d", &grade);

        if (grade != -1) {
            numberofGrades++;
            sumofGrades += grade;
        }
    }

    average = sumofGrades / numberofGrades;
    printf("The average is %.2f\n", average);

    return average;
}
```

#### Update

I'm still having issues! I can't get the program to ask me to enter the grades four times and calculate the average each time!! I tried and I tried and it's so frustrating!! What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Note that a malicious user could enter 30 grades of -100 and your program wouldn't object.  I have doubts about how realistic that scoring is.  (You should check that the grade is valid a little more carefully than you are at the moment.)  There's no point in calculating the average in the loop; you only know the answer at the end.  It isn't clear why you pass the numbers zero to the function; they'd both be better as local variables (local to the function, that is, not `main()`), as long as they are properly initialized.

Comment: this line: `for (i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {` while it is not a problem in this specific instance, will give you lots of problems when 'i' is used within the loop,  especially if 'i' is used to index into an array.    Suggest getting into the habit of writing such a for loop as: `for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {`

Comment: Please consistently indent the code for ease of readability by us humans.

Comment: My homework required me to use specifically that for loop..

Comment: When calling the system function: `scanf()` and family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this line: `if (grade != -1) {` should be checking for all three conditions so out-of-bounds values are not applied to the numofgrades nor the sumofgrades variables.   Similarly, the while() loop only needs to check for the exit condition.  (and if a out-of-bounds value were entered by the user, the loop will (currently) exit, so no more grades will be handled.

Comment: When I run your updated code verbatim, it works correctly, reporting an average of 2.0 for (1, 2, 3, -1), 5.0 for (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -1), 31.0 for (19, 27, 25, 43, -1) and 82.0 for (90, 87, 82, 71).  It doesn't work well if the first number entered is -1 (division by zero and core dump).  Did you recompile?

Comment: this line: `average = sumofGrades / numberofGrades;` will use an integer divide,  which will round toward 0,   Suggest something similar to: `average = (float)sumofGrades / numberofGrades;` so all the math is performed in float

Comment: To avoid the divide-by-zero problem, initialize 'average' to 0.0f and check that numberofgrades is >0 before calculating the average.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've entered one valid grade, your code doesn't try to read another grade:

```
printf("Enter grades and -1 to stop: ");
scanf("%d", &grade);
while (grade <= 100 && grade != -1) {
    numberofGrades++;
    sumofGrades += grade;
    average = sumofGrades / numberofGrades;
}
```

If the grade is valid, it goes into an infinite loop.  It also calculates the average grade on each cycle, which is unnecessary.  Once, after the loop, is sufficient.

Maybe you should use:

```
printf("Enter grades and -1 to stop: ");
while (scanf("%d", &grade) == 1 && grade <= 100 && grade >= 0)
{
    numberofGrades++;
    sumofGrades += grade;
}
if (numberofGrades == 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: zero valid grades entered\n");
    average = 0.0;
}
else
{
    average = sumofGrades / numberofGrades;
    printf("The average is %.2f", average);
}
return average;
```

Note that this checks that the input was successful before using the grade.

You also really don't need to pass the variables into the function.  You'd do better to make the function accept no arguments and have the parameters as regular local variables properly initialized to zero.

Your main program should capture the average since it is returned, rather than ignore it.  Or maybe the function shouldn't return the average after all.

Answer (score 0):

First off you are looping through your calculateAverage funtion 4 times. Are you doing this on purpose? I think you should only do this once.

Second, in your while loop

```
while (grade <= 100 && grade != -1) {
    numberofGrades++;
    sumofGrades += grade;
    average = sumofGrades / numberofGrades;

}
```

you are infinitely looping. This will loop forever if a value other than -1 is entered. This should be changed to an if statement.

```
if (grade <= 100 && grade != -1)
```

But there is a better way to write this code (if I am guessing what you actually want it to do)

```
#include <stdio.h>

float calculateAverage (int sum, int size);

int main(void) 
{

    int input;
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (input != -1 && input >= 0 && input <= 100)
    {
       printf ("Enter a Grade: ");
       scanf ("%d", &input);

       if (input != -1)
       {
           sum += input;
           count++;
       }
    }

    float average = calculateAverage(sum, count);
    return 0;
}

float calculateAverage (int sum, int count) {

   // Do your average math here....
}
```

Comment: Using C++ code in a question tagged C is not a good idea.  Your basic diagnosis is fine, but giving C++ code is not.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I left the code to express the basic idea. Since this is probably his homework, this will enable him to still learn and translate this into c.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I can't get it right yet. For the assignment I need the program to ask me 4 times to input the unknown number of grades and each time the average is calculated.

Comment: If you need to have 4 different input times. Surrounding the while loop with a for loop of 4 times will work. After you come out of the first while loop you can print a message saying that time is over. Also, you can store the 4 averages (and sums) in an array of size 4.

Comment: I still can't get it right!! When I compile it asks me to enter the numbers. All good until I enter my numbers. It gives me the average only once and then it repeats "Enter grades and type -1 to stop" 4 times in a row with the same calculated average of the numbers I entered first!!

Answer (score 0):

there is no way, given the posted code, for the sub function to update the variables in the main() function.

Suggest passing pointers to the variables and modifying the sub function to expect (and properly handle) those pointers

Comment: True, but since the main doesn't try to print them, there's no harm done.  It's weird (as I've noted in both a comment and my answer), and not good programming practice, but it doesn't actually break the code.

Comment: I don't understand... sorry I'm really new

Comment: what part is bad programming practice? I want to improve.

Comment: @Cbeginner: The part that's bad programming practice is passing the two parameters to the function which could perfectly well be local variables.  You always pass two zeroes to the function; the copies of the values in the function are updated, but the updates do not affect the variables in `main()`.

Comment: Can you give an example?